# How to print occurrence of a character in string in alphabetical order in C#?

Tags: c#, string, sorting

Can anyone help me to find most efficient way to print character occurrence along with that character in a given string in alphabetical order?

I am able to count occurrence of character in string but I am not able to sort it in alphabetical order.

```
string OutputString = string.Empty;
int count = 1;
char[] charArr = inputString.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < charArr.Length; j++) {
        if (charArr[i] == charArr[j])
            count++;
    }
    if (!OutputString.Contains(charArr[i]))
        OutputString += charArr[i].ToString() + count.ToString();

    count = 1;
}
OutputString = string.Concat(OutputString.OrderBy(c => c));
```

let's say input string in `xgdgyd`

output should be:

```
d2g2x1y1.
```

Comment: You should count all the characters before you start working on building the results.

Comment: I'd start sorting the string, then count the number of occurrences of each different char. Getting the string you need should be easy after that

Comment: Do you want to separate upper and lower case?

Comment: sounds like homework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Linq to simplify this:

```
string s = "xgdgyd";

var result = s
   .GroupBy(c => c)
   .Select(g => g.Key.ToString() + g.Count())
   .OrderBy(x => x);

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(result)); // Outputs "d2g2x1y1"
```

The most useful thing here is `GroupBy()`, which will group all identical items together. That allows us to use `g.Count()` to count the number of items in each group.

Then we just concatenate each group key (a char) with its count into a single string.

[Example on .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XzJzdY).

(I've simplified the code to use string.Concat() rather than string.Join() here.)

Comment: I think that, formally, you should do the OrderBy after the GroupBy, therefore after the Select. Which should work for these string values.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, that would reduce the number of items to be sorted.

Comment: That too but I don't think that GroupBy promises to preserve the order of the input.

Comment: Always love seeing long code condensed into elegant Linq :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually, `GroupBy()` does preserve the order - [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8): `Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.`

Comment: That's _inside_ a grouping, but the relevant part is just before that. So moving the orderby is just an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by @Matthew with LINQ is perfect, but if you want a solution with for loops as you posted in question then do this.

sort inputString first, and remove the line of code that sorts OutputString at the end, like this::

```
string inputString = "xgdgyd";

inputString = string.Concat(inputString.OrderBy(c => c));

string OutputString = string.Empty;
int count = 1;
char[] charArr = inputString.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
{
  for (int j = i + 1; j < charArr.Length; j++)
  {
    if (charArr[i] == charArr[j])
      count++;
  }
  if (!OutputString.Contains(charArr[i]))
    OutputString += charArr[i].ToString() + count.ToString();

  count = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you might not yet know LINQ, here is a solution using "classic" techniques:

```
string input = "xgdgyd";
char[] charArr = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Sort(charArr); // Sort before counting as Gian Paolo suggests!
                     // ==> "ddggxy"
int count;
string output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i += count) { // Increment by count to get
                                                  // the next different char!
    count = 1;
    // Note that we can combine the conditions within the for-statement
    for (int j = i + 1; j < charArr.Length && charArr[j] == charArr[i]; j++) {
        count++;
    }
    output += charArr[i] + count.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(output); // ==> d2g2x1y1
```

Note that the increment `i += count`, which is equivalent to `i = i + count` is performed at the end of the for-loop. Therefore `count` will be initialized at this point.

---

Another variant that uses only one loop instead of two nested loops appends the previous character to the output and resets the counter as soon as a different character is found.

```
string input = "xgdgyd";
char[] charArr = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Sort(charArr); // Sort before counting as Gian Paolo suggests!

int count = 1;
string output = "";
for (int i = 1; i < charArr.Length; i++) {
    if (charArr[i] == charArr[i - 1]) {
        count++;
    } else {
        output += charArr[i - 1] + count.ToString();
        count = 1;
    }
}
// Output last char
output += charArr[charArr.Length - 1] + count.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

---

A more advanced technique would be to use a `StringBuilder`. See [Concatenating Strings Efficiently](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html) by Jon Skeet.